# Route 53 won't let me add to the existing SPF record for a client because the string is too long

Tags: amazon-route53

I am trying to add 2 entries to a client's existing SPF record in Route 53, but I'm getting the following error:

*CharacterStringTooLong (Value is too long) encountered with '"v=spf1

```
ip4:27.127.198.240 ip4:52.63.207.103 include:spf.antispamcloud.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:transmail.net include:spf.levart.com.au include:spf.smtp2go.com include:servers.mcsv.net a:spf.inspectionmanager.com a:spf.propertyspace.com include:e.jobadder.com ~all"', Duplicate Resource Record: "google-site-verification=LoYtmNmUIF8G2zgInlqxcJDvlrV19_w5I72mD9*
```

The 2 entries I tried to add are:

1. `a:spf.inspectionmanager.com`
2. `a:spf.propertyspace.com`

Can someone please let me know the correct way to split the string to get around the 255 character limit?

Comment: You mat have another obstacle as well. There are limits to the number of resources referred to in an SPF record. My bet is you've exceeded them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [blog](https://www.mailhardener.com/blog/how-to-enter-txt-values-in-google-cloud-dns) post about splitting long > 255 char TXT records which has the following conclusion:

> You'll need to split long values into parts of 255 characters and wrap
>   your input in double quotes. You can use our DNS record splitter to do
>   that.

Although they write about google cloud dns, the same is true also for Route53.

You can have a peek at the octodns package, which handles splitting to character length for Route53 (and others) [like so](https://github.com/github/octodns/blob/master/octodns/record/__init__.py#L1088):

```
class _ChunkedValuesMixin(_ValuesMixin):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 255
    _unescaped_semicolon_re = re.compile(r'\w;')

    def chunked_value(self, value):
        value = value.replace('"', '\\"')
        vs = [value[i:i + self.CHUNK_SIZE]
              for i in range(0, len(value), self.CHUNK_SIZE)]
        vs = '" "'.join(vs)
        return '"{}"'.format(vs)
```

So just splitting the text into chunks of 255 characters, and surround the chunks with double quotes `"` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon explains this here: [When I try to create a TXT record using SPF syntax, I get the error ”CharacterStringTooLong (Value is too long) encountered with {Value}". How can I fix this?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/characterstringtoolong-error/?nc1=h_ls)

The workaround is to create multiple records instead of one

> You can store some validated IP addresses in a TXT SPF record and then
>   store the rest in a second one